# Python lxml error in Google Colab even after installing lxml with pip and pip3

Tags: lxml, google-colaboratory

from lxml import etree command gives the below error in google colab:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
But if I try to install it with the command !pip3 install lxml or !pip install lxml it gives the below:
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (4.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Mention of `/root/.local/lib` is strange and makes me think your VM is confused by earlier attempts. If you "reset all runtimes" to get a fresh VM does the following work for you?  (it does for me)

```
!pip install lxml
from lxml import etree
help(etree)
```